# Difference between Convert.ToBase64String/Convert.FromBase64String and Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes/Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Tags: c#, cryptography

I currently am learning Symmetric Cryptography in .NET. I wrote a demo as following:

```
    private byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefgh");
    private byte[] IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hgfedcba");
    private byte[] encrypted;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox2.Text = this.Encrypt(this.textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox3.Text = this.Decrypt(this.textBox2.Text);
    }

    private string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DESCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                crypto.Key = this.key;
                crypto.IV = this.IV;

                ICryptoTransform transform = crypto.CreateEncryptor(crypto.Key, crypto.IV);

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(plainText);
                        }

                        encrypted = stream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        try
        {
            string plainText = string.Empty;

            using (DESCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                crypto.Key = this.key;
                crypto.IV = this.IV;

                ICryptoTransform transform = crypto.CreateDecryptor(crypto.Key, crypto.IV);

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            plainText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plainText;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Everything work as expected. But if I replace

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
```

And

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)))
```

To

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
```

And

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cipherText)))
```

I got an error at CryptoStream `System.NotSupportedException`. After diagnostic the code, I found that `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cipherText)` have more bytes than `encrypted`

So what is the difference between using `Convert.From/ToBase64String` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes/GetString)` ?

Comment: You mean besides the obvious: They are two very different encoding mechanisms?

Comment: Actually, I want to know more about the encoding mechanism that make the difference between them and what should I have to consider in order to choose one over the other.

Comment: That's not really a topic that can be covered quickly here.  I would suggest you start by searching Google/Bing for each topic and then come back when you have specific questions regarding the implementation details.  Each encoding is so radically different.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a character encoding. It encodes Unicode codepoints (characters) into bytes.

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a binary-to-text encoding. It encodes bytes to text.

You need the latter in this case.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString` *decodes* a UTF-8-encoded byte array, which is lossy if there are invalid byte sequences (which is highly likely if you feed it random bytes like a ciphertext).